# How can I convert a nonlinear voltage function to linear?

Tags: analog, signal

I have a linear voltage as an input signal, and I'd like to use an analog circuit to fit this to a nonlinear curve of the form [represented by this graph from 0-150](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=graph%20degrees(atan(x%2F87.6))) (atan(x/87.6) for reference).  What kind of circuit can I use to shape my input signal to match this expected contour?

Comment: You aren't seriously considering converting \$150\:\textrm{V}\$ as an input into about \$60\:\textrm{V}\$ as an output, are you?

Comment: How accurately do you want this functional transformation to occur? How fast it should work? And more importantly, why? More, the title says you want to convert a nonlinear function to linear, but the body of question says opposite. What kind a problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: I'm converting a 1-5v input signal to a 1-5v output to drive an air core gauge.  I'd like the air core gauge angle to vary linearly with the input signal.

Comment: How about a microcontroller with a few analog IO pins and a math library?

Comment: That's looking like the simplest solution at the moment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have done this very function with a computer look-up table as Michael's answer has suggested.
 An analog approach is possible with a network of diodes and scaling resistors since your function is monotonic. However since diodes are involved, temperature effects should also be considered. Transistors can also be used as the non-linear element, instead of diodes.
Since accuracy isn't specified, the number of resistor-diode pairs required in this piece-wise approach isn't known. Be assured that high accuracy requires many. One of a few circuit possibilities goes like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3R5Fs.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>
The left-most circuit has the basic shape of your function, with R1 and R2 setting the slope of Vout1/Vin1 near zero. As Vin1 magnitude increases, diodes limit Vout1 to about +/- 0.7 V (affected by temperature). Vout1 would have to be scaled by a following linear amplifier.
The right-most circuit adds extra diode-resistors to improve compliance with your function in a piece-wise manner. For higher compliance, more sections can be added.

Such diode-resistor networks were used in sine-square-triangle function generators to convert a triangle wave-shape to a sine waveshape. You might find more circuit ideas from function generator schematics:
[image: triangle-to-sine diode-resistor network]

Answer (score 3):

Trying to do this problem with an analog only circuit can be very difficult. So I recommend looking for an alternate solution.

The easiest way to do this, provided the rate of change of the linearly varying input signal is relatively show, is to feed the input signal into a microcontroller with an A/D converter input. You may want to scale the linear signal using an op-amp to get your input signal to fit over the range of the A/D converter input. This will convert the input voltage into a digital number. Lets say the A/D that you select supports 10 bits then you may see input values ranging from say 0 to just under 1023 with a properly scaled input.

Next compute a lookup table using a spreadsheet that you run on your PC that converts the relative 0 to 1023 range to the desired translation values. This table then can be extracted from the spreadsheet and made into a number table to be included in the software for the microcontroller.

Hopefully the microcontroller has a similar 10-bit D/A converter. Software would repeatedly read the A/D values, translate through the lookup table and set the D/A converter value accordingly. Depending upon the nature of your application you may want to buffer the D/A output with an op-amp that could also scale the output as well.

Not all microcontrollers come with D/A converters and so a second choice is to produce the output voltage using a timer to make a PWM waveform whose duty cycle is specified by the look up table output. The varying duty cycle waveform can then be filtered with an R/C low pass filter to produce the output voltage. A filter like that will also most likely need to be op-amp buffered if you do not have a high impedance load.

Comment: I agree with this answer, but the OP expressly asked for an analog circuit (folly though that may be)

Comment: In some sense any circuit is analog :)

Comment: @GregoryKornblum , or, as one of my schoolmates used to say 40+ years ago, "best analog circuit is the digital one" :-)

Comment: I like this, didn't think of going digital because I assumed analog would be a simpler and more compact solution.  I think an attiny85 via Arduino would probably do the trick and fit into the packaging I'm looking at!

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to go with this approach.  I was hoping that an analog solution would be simpler but based on the answer in analog form it seems that this isn't the case.